# gsl library: gslcblas library not found but installed

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, libraries, octave

I have problems with installing the gsl package. Running Xubuntu 18.04, octave 4.4.1.

Using -forge, the installation process stalls with the following message:

```
 pkg install -forge gsl
 configure: error: gslcblas library not found
```

I have installed via synaptic: `libgslcblas0`, `libgsl-dev`, `libgsl23`

Can anybody give me instructions on what to do now?

I asked this yesterday on the octave mail list, but got only the answer to install `gslclbas`, which is already installed.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your advice N0rbert, but sorry the advice installing `liboctave-dev` did not work for me.

I get:

```
pkg install -forge gsl
configure: error: gslcblas library not found
checking for mkoctfile... /app/bin/mkoctfile-4.4.1
checking for octave... /app/bin/octave-4.4.1
checking for Octave's canonical_host_type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for Octave's include directory... /app/include/octave-4.4.1/octave
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ov-scalar.h usability... yes
checking ov-scalar.h presence... yes
checking for ov-scalar.h... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... no
pkg: error running the configure script for gsl.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 184 column 7
    pkg at line 437 column 9
```

Any other ideas?

I tried it with Octave 4.2.2. on another PC, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Octave development package first with:

```
sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

With standard Octave 4.2.2 from official Ubuntu repositories this results in successful installation of internal `gsl` package.

```
>> pkg load gsl
>> gsl_sf_sinc(0)
ans =  1
```

---

For your information: Ubuntu provides [`octave-gsl` package ver. 2.1.0-3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=octave-gsl), while Octave Forge provides [ver. 2.1.1](https://octave.sourceforge.io/gsl/index.html) - [NEWS file](https://octave.sourceforge.io/gsl/NEWS.html) contains note:

> ```
> ===============================================================================  
> gsl-2.1.1  
> ===============================================================================  
>
> ** Octave 4.4 compatibility fixes (remove deprecation warnings)
> ```

So you can use Octave from repositories.

Comment: @ N0rbert sorry that does not work for me. See my edit above. Still the same error message.