# installing gslcblas on octave (installed via flatpak)

Tags: octave, flatpak

Installing gslcblas on octave is not a big challenge ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096767/gsl-library-gslcblas-library-not-found-but-installed/1146495?noredirect=1#comment1903512_1146495)).
But how can I solve the same problem, when octave is installed via flatpak on Ubuntu 18.04?

```
>> pkg install -forge gsl

Gtk-Message: 15:39:59.007: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:39:59.007: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:39:59.306: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:39:59.308: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
configure: error: gslcblas library not found
checking for mkoctfile... /app/bin/mkoctfile-5.1.0
checking for octave... /app/bin/octave-5.1.0
checking for Octave's canonical_host_type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for Octave's include directory... /app/include/octave-5.1.0/octave
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ov-scalar.h usability... yes
checking ov-scalar.h presence... yes
checking for ov-scalar.h... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... no

pkg: error running the configure script for gsl.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 184 column 7
    pkg at line 441 column 9
```

In this case `sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev` does not work.